# Bringing a subview to be in front of all other views

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I am working on integrating an ad provider into my app currently. I wish to place a fading message in front of the ad when the ad displays but have been completely unsuccessful.

I made a function which adds a subview to my current view and tries to bring it to the front using

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:mySubview]
```

The function fires on notification that the ad loaded (the notification is from the adprovider's SDK). However, my subview does not end up in front of the ad. I imagine this is made purposely difficult by the ad provider, but I wish to do it regardless. I am currently discussing with the provider whether or not this can be allowed. But for the time being, I just want to see if it's even possible.

Is there anyway I can force a subview of mine to be the top-most view such that it will not be obstructed by anything?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

What if the ad provider's view is not added to `self.view` but to something like `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`?

Try something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourSubview]
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:yourSubview]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for iAd banner views... which is a common "needs to be on top" problem. (iAds are not allowed in non-VCs)

Comment: or [parentview bringSubviewToFront:yourSubview]    , where parentview is the inmediate view of the subview

Answer (score 181):

try this:

```
self.view.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Was useful for a Map pin issue (I wanted to force one on top of the others)

Comment: Can I ask why you sent this reply 3 years after this question was posted?

Comment: i was searching 3 years after the solution =)

Comment: Unfortunately this can not change the gesture responding order.

Comment: This only puts the view in front, but not all the gesture and touch events.  so  when the user tries to touch the view,  it will touch some other view.   The solution by @jere is the correct one.

Comment: i was searching 12 years after the solution =)

Comment: how to make the above view active

Comment: Well if you do this repeatedly for some arbitrary close by views, they both have zPosition == 1, and that's not ok. (without custom zPosition logic)

Answer (score 23):

Swift 2 version of Jere's answer:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.bringSubviewToFront(YourViewHere)
```

Swift 3:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: YourViewHere)
```

Swift 4:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubviewToFront(YourViewHere)
```

Hope it saves someone 10 seconds! ;)

Comment: What if I want to bring the keyWindow itself to the front ? I am facing an issue where the keyWindow stays on the back for some reason...

Answer (score 18):

I had a need for this once. I created a custom `UIView` class - `AlwaysOnTopView`.

```
@interface AlwaysOnTopView : UIView
@end

@implementation AlwaysOnTopView

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.superview && [keyPath isEqual:@"subviews.@count"]) {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    if (self.superview) {
        [self.superview removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"subviews.@count"];
    }

    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    if (self.superview) {
        [self.superview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"subviews.@count" options:0 context:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Have your view extend this class. Of course this only ensures a subview is above all of its sibling views.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 8):

As far as i experienced zposition is a best way.

> self.view.layer.zPosition = 1;

Answer (score 2):

Let me make a conclusion. **In Swift 5**

You can choose to addSubview to keyWindow, if you add the view in the last.
Otherwise, you can bringSubViewToFront.

```
let view = UIView()
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(view)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

You can also set the zPosition. But the drawback is that you can not change the gesture responding order.

```
view.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In c#, View.BringSubviewToFront(childView);
       YourView.Layer.ZPosition = 1;
both should work.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4.2**

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront#declarations

Comment: No they changed in Swift 4.2, Please have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront#declarations @LuigiTaira