# Display new iOS UIView everywhere in existing app

Tags: ios, uiview, always-on-top

I simply want to display a basic UIView in the top right corner of an existing app. 
The app is very complex with many different view controllers and layouts. 
What is the easiest way to create a view once and make sure it stays on screen over the top of any other view that appears?

The only way I can think of is inserting the view into every view controller. But I need to maintain the same instance of the view throughout the app and I don't want to have to do this every time we add a new view controller to the app.

Comment: perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13182569/1336105

Comment: Different question, but correct answer. Thanks!



`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourSubview]`